# In how many ways can we place $k$ distinct objects into $n$ identical boxes if each box contains atmost one object

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> In how many ways can we place $k$ distinct objects into $n$ identical
>   boxes if each box contains at most one object?

Interpreting it as permuting n objects taken k at a time.So,there are $\binom{k}{n}\times n!$ ways.

Am i correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Informally:**

Each object goes into a box by itself.  This can only be done one way if $k\leq n$ and zero ways if $k>n.$

---

**More Formally:**

We are counting the number of partitions of $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ with at most $n$ parts and each part has at most one element.

Since each part has at most one element, there is only one such candidate: $$\{\{1\}, \{2\}, \ldots, \{k\}\}$$

- If $k \leq n,$ then this partition satisfies the requirements of the problem, so there is exactly one such partition.
- If $k > n,$ then this partition has too many parts, so there are zero such partitions.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @RobArthan Why doesn't it? I think it perfectly answers it.

Comment: @RobArthan Unless you're simply pointing out that the question is "Am i correct?" and my answer didn't state "No", I honestly don't know what your argument is.  If you want to clarify how you think my answer is deficient, please do so.

Comment: I've added a bit more formal solution in case that was your concern.

Comment: The question is about putting $k$ objects into $n$ boxes. Given 3 boxes and 2 objects, there are several ways that I can put the objects into the boxes so that each box contains at most one object.

Comment: @RobArthan The boxes are **identical.**  In your instance with 3 boxes and 2 objects, you put object 1 in a box, you put object 2 in another box, and you leave one box empty.  There's no other way to do it.

Comment: That's an interesting interpretation of the word "identical" in the question. However, there are said to be $n$ identical boxes, so they can't really be identical unless $n \le 1$. So the question needs some clarification?

Comment: @RobArthan "can't be identical unless $n\leq 1$" is perhaps debatable as a matter of definition (certainly you are right if we mean "logically identical").  I can at least grant that "identical" is a loaded/vague term.  The usual, more clear, term thrown around is "indistinguishable."

Comment: So the question does need clarification? (And I can't think of an interpretation of the terms in the question that makes your answer work for me - the word "identical" probably shouldn't be there)

Comment: @RobArthan I'm pretty firm in my belief I've interpreted it the way the original author intended (especially with how ubiquitous the [the twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way) is in these types of questions) but I'm never going to argue against someone needing clarification.